# Return type from Try in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am trying to count number of records, and if i get them return the records else just log the error.

Following is the snippet:

```
    val records: Any = Try(count()) match {
                case Success(records) => records
                case Failure(exception) => logger.error(s"Exception occurred")
              }
```

The data type of count method is Int but because of wrapping it in Try, getting type as any. 
How can i solve the problem?

Comment: What should the value of `records` be if there is an error?

Comment: nothing just log error

Comment: That is what the code is already doing. The error case returns nothing (`Unit` in Scala terms) so the expression is either `Int` or `Unit` and the only type that matches both of those is `Any`. It you want it to be `Int` you have to return `Int` in the error case as well as the success case.

Answer (score 2):

what is a return type of `count` method / field returns. If you want just ignore the exception and print it then continue, you should have done something like this:

```scala
  val records: List[Int] = Try(count()) match {
    case Success(records) => records
    case Failure(exception) =>
      log.error("Exception occurred", exception)
      List.empty
  }

  def count(): List[Int] = List(1, 2 ,3)
```